# PHP WHILE LOOP until it someone insert to the game

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

im using YII FRAMEWORK right now, im kinda developing this game USING PHP.

i like to know what is the right codes for the problem i like to solve..

i try to use if-else thou i think while loop would be the answer.

I have this database name `gameWaiting` and i have this `button` on my game name `createGame`

so when the player click the button `createGame` it will now insert to the database.

While it was in the database named `gameWaiting` meaning this player was waiting for another player.

then when another player click the createGame this player will automatically load the game.

But how can i loop my codes to wait for another player...

is this the correct code?

```
$game = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM game " );
while( $game_is_not_empty_loop > empty($game) ){
  // CODES HERE
}
```

I try to use `if else` but it stop waiting for the game.
I also try to put sleep(30) so it will wait for another player but i guess that would not be useful...

help me please.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create socket-based game? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/ and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible by while loop. I have such type already created a game already. To resolve you need to create an algorithm and need to manage highly optimized data fields to find who is waiting player and who is second player.It is something too complex.

Answer (score 1):

No, your code is wrong. You query the database only once, and you will never know of games created afterwards.

So the first solution would be to constantly query the database until a game is found.

DONT DO IT! It will probably kill your database.

Find another was of inter-process-communication, or query the database less often. Every 10 seconds might be ok, or even less.